# cakephp assocations issue in 2x

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have two tables

- `messages`
- `users`

`users` has roles `Doctor` and `user`.

`messages` has `doc_id` & `user_id`.

How do I make an association, so that it returns me both data  `doc_id` & `user_id` from `users`.

Comment: Why `doc_id`, `user_id` differently?

Comment: Please update your question with a little more clarity, and perhaps even some context.

Comment: user id is for different functionality and doc id for diffrent . user send message to doctor. so doc id and user id in message.

Comment: what functionality? simple user type could do this i think.

Comment: user user_id which user sending Message for a doctor doc_id. that's reason im saving both for record.

Answer (score 0):

For the Role association on User you will need a join table, thats if i am right in believing a User can have many roles?

You'r Message model should only have a BelongsTo User, then when  your doing loop ups you will use deep associations in your find methods to bring back some like...

```
// Find with deep assosiations
$this->Message->find('all', array());


Array
(
    [Message] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [body] => example body...
        )

    [User] => Array
        (
            [username] => John
            [Role] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => 6
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class  Message extends AppModel {
  public $hasMany=array('MessageDetail');

    public $belongsTo = array(
                        'User'=>array(
                          'className'=>'User',
                          'foreignKey'=>'user_id',
                        ),
                      'Doctor'=>array(
                          'className'=>'User',
                          'foreignKey'=>'doc_id'
                        ),
                      'Petprofiles'=>array(
                          'className'=>'PetProfiles',
                          'foreignKey'=>'petprofiles_id'
                      )
                      );
}
```